# Set Lock Screen and Background image in windows phone 8.1(winrt) using c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to set my lock screen and background image using c# in windows phone 8.1(WinRT) app.I have a button which jobs is to change lock screen by selecting the image from the gallery or made at runtime .Is there any api or specific tutorial  or document available ?

Need help?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to set the lock-screen wallpaper in a Windows Runtime Phone app at this time - you need to keep using Silverlight to use the lock screen API.

[MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206968(v=vs.105).aspx)

**EDIT:**

Not applicable to 8.1, but there is now an API for setting the Start Screen and Lock Screen backgrounds in Windows 10 - [`UserProfilePersonalizationSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.aspx). The API is universal, but it only does something meaningful on Desktop and Mobile (the `IsSupported` property is `true`). On other platforms like Xbox, it just fails silently (no exception, but no background is set either).